# iPhone 5 (or just retina) resizableImageWithCapInsets not working as expected

Tags: iphone, uitableview, image-resizing, iphone-5

I'm out of ideas.  I'm trying to use `resizableImageWithCapInsets` to set the background image on my table cells.  My expected cap insets work fine on iPhone Simulator, iPhone 3GS device, but **NOT on my iPhone Simulator (4 Retina) or iPhone 5 simulator/device.**

Retina (iPhone4 or iPhone5) version
[image]

Regular version
[image]

It also happens to only be a problem with the middle table cell.  It works fine for my top and bottom table cell images, but nothing seems to work for the middle cell.

`define UIEDGE_INSET_TABLE_CELL_MIDDLE UIEdgeInsetsMake(1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0)`

The image is then created as so:

`[[UIImage imageNamed:@"table-middle-cell"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEDGE_INSET_TABLE_CELL_MIDDLE];`

[image] : here is my regular version of the table cell

[image] : here is my retina version of the table cell

Attached is my table cell resizable image, a screenshot from an iPhone 4 vs. iPhone 5.  Does anyone know where my problem is?

Comment: Do you have both `table-middle-cell.png` and `table-middle-cell@2x.png`? Is the 2nd twice the size of the 1st?

Comment: Sure is!  I was having troubles with the *2x* image my designer gave me, so I went ahead and just scaled up ```table-middle-cell``` 200% and set it as the *2x* image.  Both cases still cause similar problems. :S

Comment: Any love, fellow SO's?  I'm sure it's the differences in my asset, but I don't know what to do to fix it! ANY advice greatly appreciated! :)